# JavaFX 2.2 bidirectional communication in javascript and webview

Tags: javascript, html, webview, javafx-2

I am working on JavaFX 2.2, I am using webview to integrate html code in the JavaFX scene and was able to load the html correctly. I was following [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx) link and was trying to pass some objects from javascript to webview/controller but I am getting null values at java side.

I have saved a interface object in JSObject like below

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov,
                State oldState, State newState) {
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                        win.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

I have created a class

```
public class JavaApp {

        public void exit() {
           Platform.exit();
        }
        public void print(Date date) {
            System.out.println("Parm:"+date);
         }
        public Date getValue() {
            return new Date();
         }
    }
```

My html is

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callJava(){
            app.print(new Date());
            var val = app.getValue();
            app.print(val);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Help</p>    
<p><a href="about:blank" onclick="callJava();">Exit the Application</a></p>    
</body>
</html>
```

In above code I always get null values printed in JavaApp.print() method. Interesting point is when I changed the parameter from Date to String in print method and pass the string from javascript, I get correct values.

How I can transfer objects in this case especially Date object. Any help is much appritiated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Java** does not know the `Date` class of **javascript**.

[2.3 Data Type Conversions](http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/index.html#JS_OTHER_OBJECTS)

You can pass a **javascript** object to **Java**, ( you have to wrap it in a `JSObject` ) but you can get directly only parameters like these:

- *Numbers*,
- *Boolean*,
- *String*,
- *arrays*,
- The same object which you have *put* into javascript before.

---

My solution for you:

```
public class JavaApp {

    public void exit() {
       Platform.exit();
    }
    //public void print(Date date) {
    //    System.out.println("Parm:"+date);
    // }
    public void print(long date) {
        System.out.println("Parm:"+new Date(date));
     }
    public Date getValue() {
        return new Date();
     }
}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callJava(){
            // app.print(new Date());
            app.print(new Date().getTime());
            var val = app.getValue();
            app.print(val);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Help</p>    
<p><a href="about:blank" onclick="callJava();">Exit the Application</a></p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answered the issue for me. I had to serialize and deserialize my Java object to/from JSON to be able to get things working well. Using GSON was quick and easy and things now work. This should be marked as the correct answer.