# Passing Java Array into JavaScript (via JSNI) and back out to Java results in null value

Tags: gwt, webview, javafx-2, jsni, javafx-webengine

Scenario: I have a GWT web application running within a JavaFX WebView/WebEngine. I am able to pass Strings from GWT to JavaScript to JavaFX without any issues.

Problem: When passing an array of custom objects like Data[] in the same fashion, the result on the JavaFX side is null.

An example of what Data looks like:

```
public class Data extends Serializable
{
  char[] name;
  int code;
  short bar;
}
```

Here's the code to send the data to JavaScript:

```
public static native void doNativeStuff(String id, Data[] data) /*-{
  $wnd.javaInterface.doStuff(id, data);
}-*/;
```

I've verified in the debugger that the Java object being passed in is populated with data and looks good.

Now on the JavaFX side, I have the following code to add the javaInterface to the page:

```
JSObject win = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
win.setMember("javaInterface", new JavaInterface());
```

I know that this works because I'm using it for other methods that pass only Strings and they work great.

```
public void doStuff(String id, Data[] data)
{
  // Right here, id == "validId" and data == null
  if (data != null)
  {
    ... do what is needed ...
  }
}
```

Note that the Data object is defined and accessible on both sides.

From the GWT documentation:

```
Incoming Java type    How it appears to JavaScript code
Java array            opaque value that can only be passed back into Java code
```

I'm not touching it in JavaScript at all and I'm only passing it through from Java->JavaScript->Java, but the final step appears to be what is failing.

I've spent the last few hours scouring Stack Overflow, Google, GWT groups, gwtproject.org, etc. But most all of the examples only show a single argument being passed through and almost none of them show a Java Array being used.

I'd much rather just pass the object through rather than going to->from JSON, but I did give that a try out of desperation. I tried to use GSON but it doesn't work on the GWT client side. I tried to use the GWT AutoBean Framework but my Data object isn't a valid bean (I think because of no default constructor) and I cannot change that at this time.

I'm not using any Long or long values.

I've seen examples like this:

```
@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::staticFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);
```

But from what I can tell that's just for going from JavaScript to GWT over JSNI. I'm trying to go the other way. I also couldn't find an example of this for multiple arguments.

I'm sure that there is just a minor tweak here that I'm missing, but I haven't been able to figure it out just yet. Please let me know if you see something that I'm missing here.

Comment: First things first: does JavaFX allows you to pass these objects that way? Try with plain JS first.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Trying that out led me to the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194326/javafx-2-2-bidirectional-communication-in-javascript-and-webview?rq=1 . It looks like I will need to serialize the data on the server before sending it to GWT, then pass that serialized JSON (String) over to JavaFX. Finally JavaFX will need to deserialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> opaque value that can only be passed back into Java code

I think this means you cannot pass Java array into JavaScript code.

Agree with **jat**. I used to provide support for the similar needs and I had to serialize the objects myself.
And you can pass multiple arguments like this (types of arguments are given just for example):

```
private native void doJSAction(MyClass handler)/*-{
    // do smth in JS

    // then call external non-static method
    handler.@com.myclient.helper.MyClass::doMyAction(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/myclient/helper/MyClass;II)(jsNativeSmth, myString, handler, intA, intB);
}-*/;
```

where `doMyAction` is something like the following:

```
void doMyAction(JavaScriptObject jsObject, String s, MyClass instance, int a, int b)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Serialization did indeed work. Also thank you for answering my other question on the format of multiple non-primitive arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played with JavaFX, but since it runs in a different VM and knows nothing about the GWT DevMode protocol (for example, a Java object is wrapped in a JS object that basically makes RPC calls to manipulate it), I am pretty sure you are going to have to serialize everything between GWT and JavaFX as Strings and primitives.